# How to use 'FindRoot' to get parameters by using solutions from ParametricNDSolve?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving

How could I get unknown parameters b,and c by using solutions from ParametricNDSolve? My solution working fine with single value for parameter Dr, but not working with list of values! Also, at the end how may I plot these values b and c with the corresponding values of Dr? Any help will be appreciated.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
Br = 3; tstar = -7; Dr = Range[20, 30, 1];(*parameters*)
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{y'[t] == -Sin [x[t]]/y[t], x'[t] == -Cos [x[t]] (6  Sin  [x[t]]  Cos  [x[t]] + y[t] (b - c (1 + 3* y[t]^2)))/(2* y[t]^3*(b + c (y[t]^2 - 1))), v'[t] == -(b + c*(y[t]^2 - 1))/(4*y[t]* Cos [x[t]]) + Sin [x[t]]/(2 *y[t]^2), x[tstar] == 0, y[tstar] == Br, v[tstar] == Log[Dr]}, {x, y, v}, {t, 0, tstar}, {b, c}] & /@ Dr
FindRoot[{(y[b, c][0] - 1) /. sol, v[b, c][0] /. sol}, {{b, 1}, {c, 1}}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Br = 3; tstar = -7;(*parameters*)
```

Let `Dr` be another parameter

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{y'[t] == -Sin[x[t]]/y[t], 
    x'[t] == -Cos[
        x[t]] (6 Sin[x[t]] Cos[x[t]] + y[t] (b - c (1 + 3*y[t]^2)))/(2*
         y[t]^3*(b + c (y[t]^2 - 1))), 
    v'[t] == -(b + c*(y[t]^2 - 1))/(4*y[t]*Cos[x[t]]) + Sin[x[t]]/(2*y[t]^2), 
    x[tstar] == 0, y[tstar] == Br, v[tstar] == Log[Dr]}, {x, y, v}, {t, 0, 
    tstar}, {b, c, Dr}];

sol2 = Table[
  FindRoot[{(y[b, c, Dr][0] - 1) /. sol, v[b, c, Dr][0] /. sol},
   {{b, 1}, {c, 1}}],
  {Dr, 20, 30}]

(* {{b -> 0.148695, c -> 0.691601}, {b -> 0.152614, 
  c -> 0.700287}, {b -> 0.156349, c -> 0.708568}, {b -> 0.159916, 
  c -> 0.716481}, {b -> 0.163331, c -> 0.724058}, {b -> 0.166605, 
  c -> 0.731325}, {b -> 0.16975, c -> 0.738308}, {b -> 0.172776, 
  c -> 0.745027}, {b -> 0.175691, c -> 0.751501}, {b -> 0.178503, 
  c -> 0.757749}, {b -> 0.181219, c -> 0.763784}} *)
```

Checking,

```
Table[
  {(y[b, c, Dr][0] - 1) /. sol, v[b, c, Dr][0] /. sol} /.
   sol2[[Dr - 19]],
  {Dr, 20, 30}] // Chop[#, 10^-13] &

(* {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 
  0}, {0, 0}} *)
```

**EDIT:** To plot `b` and `c` against `Dr`

```
bcVal[Dr_?NumericQ] := 
 FindRoot[{(y[b, c, Dr][0] - 1) /. sol, 
   v[b, c, Dr][0] /. sol}, {{b, 1}, {c, 1}}]

Show[
 Plot[
    Callout[#[[1]] /. bcVal[Dr], #[[1]],
     {25, Above}, Appearance -> "Line"],
    {Dr, 20, 30},
    PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][#[[2]]]] & /@
  {{b, 1}, {c, 2}},
 PlotRange -> {0, 1},
 AxesOrigin -> {20, 0},
 AxesLabel -> {HoldForm[Dr], None}]
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot[{b, c} /. bcVal[Dr], {Dr, 20, 30},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {b, c}),
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][#3] &),
 PlotLegends -> Placed[
   BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {20, 30}},
    LegendLabel -> Dr], {.9, .4}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Again thank you so much @Bob Hanlon. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Do not ask new questions in comments. Post a new question and show what you have tried and explain with what you are having difficulty.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion.